# BoxCast не работает/Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

[отключу Use Gravity у Player'а]
Когда куб, то есть Player, не касается коллайдером с землёй, но BoxCast касается её, то hitdetect = true.
[image: Не сталкивается]
[включу Use Gravity у Player'а, т.к я не могу поставить куб так, чтобы коллайдеры прикоснулись, но куб не отлетел]
Но если куб касается коллайдером земли и BoxCast тоже, то hitdetect = false.
[image: Сталкивается]

Коллайдер куба снизу больше чем сам куб
Класс KeyboardInput

```
public class KeyboardInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(-50f, 50f)] private float _maxDistance = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private Jumper _jumper;
    public Collider collider;
    public Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.identity;
    public LayerMask _ground = 9;
    public RaycastHit hit;
    public bool hitdetect;
    private void Update()
    {
        hitdetect = Physics.BoxCast(collider.bounds.center, collider.bounds.size / 2, Vector3.down,out hit, quaternion,_maxDistance);
        if (hitdetect)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Hit : {hit.collider.name}");
            Debug.Log(hitdetect);
            
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;

        if (hitdetect)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawRay(collider.bounds.center, Vector3.down * hit.distance);
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube(collider.bounds.center + Vector3.down * hit.distance, collider.bounds.size);
        }
        else
        {
            Gizmos.DrawRay(collider.bounds.center, Vector3.down * hit.distance);
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube(collider.bounds.center + Vector3.down * _maxDistance, collider.bounds.size);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Jumper

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class Jumper : MonoBehaviour
{
     
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    [SerializeField] private float _force = 10;
    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    public void Jump()
    {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * _force); 
    }
}
```

Класс Axis

```
public static class Axis
{
    public readonly static string Horizontal = "Horizontal";
    public readonly static string Vertical = "Vertical";
    public readonly static string Jump = "Jump";
}
```

Comment: Кстати, по поводу класса Axis, познакомьтесь с перечислением `enum`, и я не понял, зачем он тут, если вы его ниаак не используете в коде. Описывается просто `public enum Axis { Horizontal, Vertical, Jump }`

Comment: Класс Axis нужен для того чтобы не работать со строками

Comment: Окей, ну тогда хотябы `static readonly` на `const` заменили бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сталкивался с тем же, сейчас опишу как я понял эту ситуацию.

Если куб касается коллайдером земли, то дистанция до земли в буквальном смысле равна 0f, из-за этого бокс кастился под землю, а так как под землей ничего нет, то и castBox ничего не встречает на своём пути, тут и получаем false.

Как я решил данную проблему - начальную точку castBox можно сдвинуть вверх на 0.01f. Теперь величина castBox не проходит сквозь землю и, луч того же castBox встречает землю, тем самым отдавая true.

```
private bool IsGrounded()
{
     const float distance = .01f;
     var bounds = boxColliderRef.bounds;

     return Physics.BoxCast(
         bounds.center + Vector3.up * distance, 
         bounds.size / 2, Vector3.down, Quaternion.identity, distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пересечение создаётся только в том направлении, которое задано BoxCast(Vector3 direction)